# invalid syntax in a simple python program

Tags: python

I'm not a programmer but I'm planning t to be so I'm learning python.
So, in this code I want to create a chronometer but when I start it python gives me an invalid syntax to the ":" of the for cycle. However if I delete them the python highlights me the n under it (in n=n+1) and gives me the same error.
What's the problem?

```
import time

def step():
    time.sleep(1)

n=0
x=int(input("How many seconds? ")
for n in range(0,x):
    n=n+1
    return n
    step()
```

Comment: don't return in your loop (that'll be your next problem)

Comment: missing closing braces in `x=int(input("How many seconds? ")` line

Comment: not much material for a good question...

Comment: You are right, now it works, thank guys! ^^

Comment: `n += 1` can be used and is simpler than `n=n+1`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an extra end parenthesis

```
x=int(input("How many seconds? ")
                                ^
                                here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing paranthesis for `int`:

```
x=int(input("How many seconds? "))  # you only had one )
```

---

Note that you probably want to `print(n)` inside the loop. The `return` will exit the loop immediatly:

```
import time

def step():
    time.sleep(1)

# No need to do "n=0"!
x=int(input("How many seconds? ")
for n in range(0,x):
    n = n + 1
    print(n)
    step()
```

Also there is no need to do the `n = n + 1` you could simply adjust the `range` (from `1` to `x+1`):

```
x=int(input("How many seconds? ")
for n in range(1, x+1):
    print(n)
    step()
```